# Wicket continueToOriginalDestination to pass parameters to original page

Tags: wicket

When `Component:continueToOriginalDestination()` is called, is there a way to pass parameters to the original destination Wicket redirects to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. At the moment (Wicket 6.8.0) there is no such API.
The collected parameters during the interception will be used.